# how to add jquery confirmation popup in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

im developing a project my own and i use codeigniter as my framework, i'm pretty begginer to php and codeignier. i created a confirm box in jquery ,but it's and html alert. so how to do that? don't laugh at me guys. thanks.

**view**

```
<?php

$_instance = get_instance();


$attributes = array('id' => 'main_form');

?>
<?php echo form_open('registration/reset',$attributes);?>

<style>
    span{
        color: red;
    }

    #main_tb{
        margin-top:100px;
    }
    </style>

<table cellspacing='10' id>




</table>

    <div id='main_form'>
    <form id="main_form" name="form">

<table CELLSPACING=2 CELLSPACING=10 id='main_tb' >

    <tr>
        <td></td>
         <td id="error"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>User Name</td>

        <td> <select class="cmb" style="width: 200px;" id="cmb_user" name="cmb_user">  </select></td>


    </tr>



     <tr>
                            <td></td>

                            <td><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('reset_error'); ?></td>

                        </tr>


    <tr>
        <td></td>

        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" id="save" value="reset password"/></td>
    </tr>


</table>
</form>

</div>


<?php echo form_close();?>
```

**script**

```
 $j('#main_form').submit(function() {
//       event.preventDefault();        
   var status = confirm("Are you sure? This cannot be undone");
   if(status == false){
   return false;
   }
   else{
   return true; 
   }
  });
```

**controller**

```
function reset(){

         $password =$_POST['cmb_user'];
      echo  $username = $this->input->post('cmb_user');


       $data_array = array(
                 'id_user' => $this->input->post('cmb_user'),

                     );
//       // echo 'sdsd';
//        echo $_POST['cmb_user'];
//        
         $this->load->model('registration/registration_model');
             $this->registration_model->reset_pass($data_array);

               $this->session->set_flashdata('reset_error', ' <br><span style="font-size: 10px;background-color: #FFFFFF;color:#ff0000;border:solid 1px #ff99cc;padding:2px;border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px">Reset Successfull</span>');
            redirect('/registration/admin_reset');
    }
```

this function works great. but i want to add jquery fancy popup like sweet alert. thank's again..

Comment: @Hassan this works as it is, but i want to add a fancy popup like messi messagebox , sweet alert. thanks for the reply.

Comment: Please post the code of `view`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code into your `view`

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/t4t5/sweetalert/master/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/t4t5/sweetalert/master/dist/sweetalert.css">
<script language="javascript">
    sweetAlert("Oops...", "Something went wrong!", "error");
</script>
```